# Script to find the last cell edited in a Google sheet has recently stopped

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, v8, triggers

Firstly I am NO programmer - but I found a pretty simple script that we have been running for years on a shared Google sheet that simply finds the last edited cell in a large amount of data. It worked brilliantly, you open the sheet and in no time you're looking at the last line that had been edited and you can begin your data entry. Recently - it simply stopped?
I'm seeing posts about V8 but looking at the script - it says it's running on V8?

```
function onOpen() {
  var ThisSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var StartingTab = ThisSheet.getSheetByName("Key# 20-30K");  // The default tab being opened
  var LastRow = ThisSheet.getLastRow() + 1;  // One past the last row that has been entered in the spreadsheet
  var LastCellString = "A"+LastRow+":A"+LastRow;  // The string representing the last cell to position to
  var LastCell = ThisSheet.getRange(LastCellString); // The internal variable of the last cell
  StartingTab.setActiveRange(LastCell)  // Actually perform the repositioning to the last cell
}
```

This is the script - any help would be very cool.

Grant

Comment: If you have just moved it perhaps you just need to to reauthorize it by running onOpen() from the script editor.

Comment: When there is a problem with a script, usually there is an error logged in the executions page. Click on View > Executions then expande the entries for onOpen function to see if there is an error. If so, add the textual error to the question.

Comment: Thanks for your answers - it's working again. It looks like I just needed to re-authorise it as per Cooper's suggestion (??) I hadn't moved it but it most certainly wasn't working before I did??

Answer (score 0):

This really isn't that much different but it does work.

```
function onOpen() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName("Key# 20-30K");
  sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow()+1,1).activate();
}
```

You do have to authorize the script before you use it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers - it's working again. It looks like I just needed to re-authorise it as per Cooper's suggestion (??) I hadn't moved it but it most certainly wasn't working before I did?? – Grant Cooper just